# Symfony EasyAdminBundle view from multiple tables

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony2-easyadmin

I need to create a view ( list ) with data from multiple tables. I use EasyAdminBundle and i have :

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
class orderes{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="datetime", type="string")
 */
private $date;

public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

/**
 * HERE I NEED GET DATA FROM ANOTHER TABLE
 */
private $test;

public function getTest()
{
    return $this->test;
}
```

Can I refer to another table in the same file?
Thanks for help.